# How to set JAVA path to JDK 8

Tags: 18.04, java, jdk, openjdk, oracle

Was trying to contribute to some open-source project. And I tried finding the answer online, tried Wikipedia how to set it.
None works.
This is getting irritating. I need to commit my work.
As I run git commit here is what I get:

```
please make sure JAVA_HOME is set to JDK8
```

Now, I use JAVA 11. I uninstalled JAVA 11 then tried installing JAVA 8. No success, tried installing 12 again JDK8 is needed.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

gives

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-oracle
```

```
java -version
```

is `12.0.2`

I want to install Java 8 and Java 12 both on my computer. And frequently shift between two.
I want to be able to work on projects which work with java 8 and those which work with java 12.

```
dpkg -L openjdk-8-jdk
```

Gives

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/jvm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/jawt.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/jconsole.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/appletviewer.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/jconsole.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/appletviewer.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/jconsole.1.gz
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-hotspot-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-jdk-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/check-langtools-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/failed_tests-hotspot.tar.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/jtreg-summary-hotspot.log.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jre-headless/test-amd64/jtreport-hotspot.tar.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "alternatives" to switch between different java versions:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And also for the java compiler (**javac**) if you are compiling some java code:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

If you installed Java 8 from apt openjdk:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Then your java home must be: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

If java 8 is not visible in **update-alternatives** you can install it with:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 1000
```

Then check it's there with:

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 : There is no such directory it is showing.

Comment: yes, JAVA_HOME is a directory not a file. It points to the root directory contianing Java install files.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config java shows me only java12. But when I do sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk. It says openjdk-8-jdk is already the newest version, that means jdk 8 is already installed

Comment: Then you probably need to tell update-alternatives where is installed the java 8:

update-alternatives  --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 1000

Comment: it is showing me error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java doesn't exist

Comment: I ran : update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 1000

Comment: Further $JAVA_HOME gives me : bash: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0: No such file or directory

Comment: If you successfully installed openjdk-8-jdk,  could you give me the output of this command ?

dpkg -L openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Ok, try to set java8 again into alternatives:

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 1000

Then check it's there with:

update-alternatives --config java

Comment: Again, it is showing me update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java doesn't exist

Comment: If file /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java does not exist, then you must reinstall java again:

    `apt purge java* openjdk*`


     `apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

If you still need java 11 install openjdk-11-jdk

Comment: This is causing me headaches. sudo apt purge java* openjdk* don't work this causes. sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk to show me no new installation.